# Timeline google chart: Remove text/label inside row

Tags: javascript, timeline

I'm using a grouped by row label timeline google chart model and I would like to **remove** the text showed inside each row. This is how it look's like now:

[time line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/818AA.png)

This is my code html/script code:

```
window.onload = function() { 
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    }; 
    function drawChart() {
        window.myChart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'));
        window.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        window.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
        window.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
        window.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        window.dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        window.dataTable.addRows([]);

        window.options = {
        //increase font size to make timeline more bigger
          timeline: {groupByRowLabel: true, showRowLabels: false, rowLabelStyle: {fontSize: 50},barLabelStyle: {fontSize: 50}},
          backgroundColor: '#000'
        };
window.myChart.draw(window.dataTable, window.options);
      }
```

And this is set on a JS file:

```
var _reloadCallback = function (info) {
    window.dataTable.removeRows(0, window.dataTable.getNumberOfRows())
    var rows = []   
    //Join datettimearrays
    window.arrayDatetimes = window.arrayDatetimes1.concat(window.arrayDatetimes2, window.arrayDatetimes3, window.arrayDatetimes4,window.arrayDatetimes5,window.arrayDatetimes6,window.arrayDatetimes7,window.arrayDatetimes8,window.arrayDatetimes9,window.arrayDatetimes10).split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < window.arrayValues.length; i++) {
        var row = []
        row.push("Interval")
        row.push(window.arrayValues[i])
        row.push ( new Date(window.arrayDatetimes[i]))
        row.push ( new Date(window.arrayDatetimes[i+1]))
        rows.push(row)
    }
    window.dataTable.addRows(rows)
    window.myChart.draw(window.dataTable, window.options);
};
```

I've tried to remove "name" column but then the timeline isn't grouped by row and shows more than one row. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.
Just setting showBarLabels to false solves my question.